# Hibernate not saving the data to the H2 database

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, h2

I am trying to get the data from a RSS Feed and put it in a H2 table. I've got already the RSS Feed but now I am trying to test to see if I can actually put it in the database.

I've tried to change the configuration of my application.properties files or of the hibernate.cfg.xml file, but to no avail. At first I thought maybe is a naming convention but I tried some variants or just adding annotations to the Entity class to just see but still not working.

This is the hibernate.cfg.xml file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>

<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>

    <session-factory>

        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">org.h2.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:h2:mem:testdbt</property>
        <property name="connection.username">sa</property>
        <property name="connection.password"/>

        <property name="hibernate.default_schema">PUBLIC</property>

        <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</property>

        <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider</property>

        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <property name="format_sql">true</property>

        <property name="use_sql_sql">true</property>

        <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</property>

        <mapping class="com.csdm.rssfeeder.model.RssFeeder"/>

    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

This is the entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Feed")
public class RssFeeder {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "TITLE")
    private String title;

    @Column(name = "DESCRIPTION")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "PUBLICATION_DATE")
    private String publicationDate;

    @Column(name = "IMAGE")
    private String image;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getPublicationDate() {
        return publicationDate;
    }

    public void setPublicationDate(String publicationDate) {
        this.publicationDate = publicationDate;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "RssFeeder{" +
                "title='" + title + '\'' +
                ", description='" + description + '\'' +
                ", publicationDate='" + publicationDate + '\'' +
                ", image='" + image + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

This is the EntityManager class:

```
SessionFactory factory = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").addAnnotatedClass(RssFeeder.class).buildSessionFactory();

        Session session = factory.getCurrentSession();

        try {
            RssFeeder rssFeeder = new RssFeeder();
            rssFeeder.setId(1);
            rssFeeder.setPublicationDate("fmm");
            rssFeeder.setTitle("fmm");
            rssFeeder.setImage("fmm");
            rssFeeder.setDescription("fmm");
            session.beginTransaction();
            session.save(rssFeeder);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        } finally {
            factory.close();
        }
    }
```

Thee is the console log. I don't know why it shows ? instead of the actual values in the console log.

```
2019-07-28 00:24:47.139  WARN 8272 --- [           main] org.hibernate.orm.deprecation            : HHH90000012: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration instead.  Support for obsolete DTD/XSD namespaces may be removed at any time.
2019-07-28 00:24:47.424  WARN 8272 --- [           main] org.hibernate.orm.connections            : HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
2019-07-28 00:24:47.427  INFO 8272 --- [           main] org.hibernate.orm.connections            : HHH10001005: using driver [org.h2.Driver] at URL [jdbc:h2:mem:testdbt]
2019-07-28 00:24:47.428  INFO 8272 --- [           main] org.hibernate.orm.connections            : HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=sa, password=****}
2019-07-28 00:24:47.428  INFO 8272 --- [           main] org.hibernate.orm.connections            : HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
2019-07-28 00:24:47.432  INFO 8272 --- [           main] .c.i.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl : HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 1 (min=1)
2019-07-28 00:24:47.436  INFO 8272 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
Hibernate: 
    drop table PUBLIC.Feed if exists
Hibernate: 
    create table PUBLIC.Feed (
        ID integer generated by default as identity,
        DESCRIPTION varchar(255),
        IMAGE varchar(255),
        PUBLICATION_DATE varchar(255),
        TITLE varchar(255),
        primary key (ID)
    )
2019-07-28 00:24:47.471  INFO 8272 --- [           main] o.h.t.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl  : HHH000476: Executing import script 'org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ScriptSourceInputNonExistentImpl@7793ad58'
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        PUBLIC.Feed
        (ID, DESCRIPTION, IMAGE, PUBLICATION_DATE, TITLE) 
    values
        (null, ?, ?, ?, ?)
2019-07-28 00:24:47.761  INFO 8272 --- [           main] .SchemaDropperImpl$DelayedDropActionImpl : HHH000477: Starting delayed drop of schema as part of SessionFactory shut-down'
Hibernate: 
    drop table PUBLIC.Feed if exists
2019-07-28 00:24:47.770  INFO 8272 --- [           main] org.hibernate.orm.connections            : HHH10001008: Cleaning up connection pool [jdbc:h2:mem:testdbt]
```

Comment: I just changed the properties to ```jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem. I had a typo on the hibernate.cfg.xml file, pointing to a wrong database.